# Why does access a pointer in a union this way cause segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, g++-5

Why does the following code cause segmentation fault?

```
#include <string>

union U {
    bool boolean;
    double number;
    std::string* str_ptr;
};

int main()
{
    U u{new std::string("A")};
    delete u.str_ptr;
    return 0;
    // return u.str_ptr->compare("A");
}
```

I should say that it does not seem to matter if I instead of the return statement try to access the pointer in some other way. E.g. replace `delete u.str_ptr; return 0;` with `return u.str_ptr->compare("A");` I still get a segmentation fault.

In case this is compiler specific I am using `g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 5.4.0 20160609`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not legal to access `u.str_ptr` unless it was [the last member set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union#Member_lifetime) in the union. But the last member set in the union is `boolean`, since an initializer list with one undesignated value sets the first member.

See "member lifetime" under [struct and union initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union).

Comment: You're citing a reference for the wrong language. Fortunately, the same (modulo designated initialisers, which don't exist) is true in C++ at time of writing (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union).

Comment: You changed the link but you kept the quote ... which doesn't exist on that page...

Answer (score 2):

`U u{new std::string("A")};` doesn't make what you think, as you said nothing special it initializes the first member with the value of the call to `new`. If you want to set the right member use the following:

```
U u{.str_ptr=new std::string("A")};
```

---EDIT---

This is `gcc` extension, standard says *When a union is initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer, the braces shall only contain an initializer-clause for the first non-static data member of the union.*. Then with standard you can only do :

```
U u;
u.str_ptr = new std::string("A");
```

Comment: Does this even compile? It looks like C99 designated initializer that is not a part of C++.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer returned by new is being implicitly converted to the type of the first member i.e., type `bool`. Since C++ allows this conversion no error occurs.

```
// effectively what is happening.
U u{ new std::string("A") != 0 };
```

When using a union like this it's probably better to be explicit and assign to members directly. But if you really want to do it this way, just make `str_ptr` the first member.